# Foreground Service freezes the ui

Tags: android, android-service

I wanted to create a simple dummy foreground task to get to know its behaviour. Unfortunately i have some problems with it. First the code:

```
public class ImageSendEmailService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ForegroundServiceTags.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION.getValue())) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String notificationText = String.valueOf((int) (100 * i / 10)) + " %";

                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
                builder.setContentTitle("Progress");
                builder.setContentText(notificationText);
                builder.setTicker("Notification!");
                builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                Notification notification = builder.build();

                this.startForeground(101, this.notification);
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The first problem i have is that the service is freezing the UI of the app. The UI is continuing after the `Service` is done with its work but is frozen while it is doing it.

The second problem i have is that when the work is done the 100% notification is shown in the notifications tab of the device and i cant delete it. I need it to be undeletable while it is doing its work but to be deletable after it finished its work.

Comment: Why is there a Thread.sleep ?

Comment: Just to pretend it to be a long running task. Without it i couldnt even see the progress because it would be 100% instantly.

Comment: Run your task on a different thread

Comment: ok. i guess ill start an asynctask inside my service than. how can i make the notification killable from notification tab when it reached 100%?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

You have to basically spawn a new thread if you wish to do a task that is going to block the main thread.

For your [notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29) problem

```
.setOngoing(true)
```

will make the notification unkillable

once your task it done, overwrite the notification with a new one with

```
.setOngoing(false)
```

For this you have to save the notification id, or just delete is yourself from code

Edit : 
You will also have to call stop self once the work is done. Rather don't mess with the notification at all. Since its a foreground service you cant remove the notification till your service is finished

Comment: Hello dexter. `.setOngoing(true)` and `.setOngoing(false)` unfortunately arent working. if i dont set any value to `setOngoing` the notification is unkillable. setting it to `.setOngoing(false)` does not change it. it stays unkillable. I used the notification id that you mentioned: `this.startForeground(IMAGE_SEND_EMAIL_SERVICE_ID, this.notification);`

Comment: You wont be able to remove the notification till you close your service. That is, once all the work is done call stopSelf() in the service

Comment: Oh but there is still something wrong now. you said i have to call `stopSelf()` to make the notification killable. The problem is when i call `stopSelf()` the notification gets killed automatically and i cant make another notification after it. Thats not what i want. I want the user to see the status, that everything is completed and that he can kill the notification when he wants it to be killed (after the work is done).

Comment: Oh. Well you will have to work a little for this. The first thing that comes to my mind is that you create the notification, the one which informs the user, from your activity after the work is done. This notification can be swiped to remove etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call `Thread.sleep(1000);` straight away as `Service` run on **main/UI** thread.

You should introduce threads (`HandlerThread` or `Thread`) to perform time-taking operations in services.

Moreover you may also look for `IntentService` which by default runs on a separate thread - sparing your UI from freeze.